# libnipalu.so failed to initialize error for all NI related commands

Tags: nidaqmx

Already, I’ve installed two DAQ cards on PCI slots of a computer with a Centos 6.9 32-bit operating systems with the kernel version 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.i686. The first one is PCI-6225 and the second is PCI-6509. I’ve followed all the steps of the instruction to update the Kernel and install the [DAQmx802f0.iso](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-8.0.2/2322/en/) driver successfully. However, now when I try to execute a command to verify the installation I just receive some errors. In more detail, I’ll elaborate on this issue as follows:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ nilsdev
libnipalu.so failed to initialize
Perhaps you need to run updateNIDrivers
Aborted
```

Unfortunately, I've run updateNIDrivers and it has been executed successfully, the problem isn't solved though.

Here are some outputs of NI routine commands:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ lsmod | grep ni
nikal                  55889  0 
[user@localhost ~]$ /etc/init.d/nipal start
/etc/init.d/nipal: line 81: /tmp/nipalk-load.log: Permission denied
FATAL: Error inserting nipalk (/lib/modules/2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.i686/kernel/natinst/nipal/nipalk.ko): Kernel does not have module support

error: nipalk failed to load
possible causes: 
   nipalk was not versioned for this kernel (2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.i686)
   modules are not enabled for this kernel (CONFIG_MODULES)
   unresolved symbols
possible solution: 
   if you recently installed a new kernel or have rebooted to
   a different kernel from one you were previously running then run
   /usr/local/bin/updateNIDrivers
   to version your NI drivers for kernel 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.i686
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

**update**: Here is the output of the command `dmesg | grep ni`

```
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
initial memory mapped : 0 - 01200000
init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000375fe000
Initializing CPU#0
Initializing HighMem for node 0 (000375fe:00400000)
Memory: 15887788k/16777216k available (4687k kernel code, 286536k reserved, 2660                                  k data, 576k init, 15268960k highmem)
      .init : 0xc0b2e000 - 0xc0bbe000   ( 576 kB)
pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
Security Framework initialized
SELinux:  Initializing.
Initializing cgroup subsys ns
Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Initializing cgroup subsys memory
Initializing cgroup subsys devices
Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
Initializing cgroup subsys perf_event
Initializing cgroup subsys net_prio
CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)
Initializing CPU#1
Initializing CPU#2
Initializing CPU#3
Initializing CPU#4
Initializing CPU#5
Initializing CPU#6
Initializing CPU#7
devtmpfs: initialized
SCSI subsystem initialized
NetLabel: Initializing
pnp: PnP ACPI init
Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Freeing initrd memory: 16721k freed
audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
type=2000 audit(1533446881.347:1): initialized
msgmni has been set to 1244
isapnp: Scanning for PnP cards...
uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Initalizing network drop monitor service
device-mapper: ioctl: 4.33.1-ioctl (2015-8-18) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
usb usb4: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has no SuperSpeed comp                                  anion descriptor
dracut: Scanning devices sda2  for LVM logical volumes VolGroup/lv_swap VolGroup                                  /lv_root
SELinux:  Completing initialization.
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-0, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev drm, type drm), not configured for labeling
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev usbfs, type usbfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev selinuxfs, type selinuxfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev inotifyfs, type inotifyfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev anon_inodefs, type anon_inodefs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev pipefs, type pipefs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev debugfs, type debugfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sockfs, type sockfs), uses task SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev devtmpfs, type devtmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev bdev, type bdev), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev rootfs, type rootfs), uses genfs_contexts
SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000f040-0x0000f05f conflicts with OpRegion 0x000                                  0f040-0x0000f04f (\_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI) (20090903/utaddress-254)
iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
SELinux: initialized (dev sda1, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev dm-2, type ext4), uses xattr
SELinux: initialized (dev binfmt_misc, type binfmt_misc), uses genfs_contexts
nikal: module license 'Copyright (c) 2002-2011 National Instruments Corporation.                                    All Rights Reserved.  Any and all use of the copyrighted materials is subject                                   to the then current terms and conditions of the applicable license agreement, wh                                  ich can be found at <http://www.ni.com/linux/>.' taints kernel.
[nipal] More than 4GB of addressable memory detected.
[nipal] This configuration is not supported.  Check the release notes for more i                                  nformation.
```

Comment: Please also add the output from `dmesg | grep ni` to show any other loading messages.

Comment: @JoeFriedrichsen Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Linux-Users/libnipalu-so-failed-to-initialize-error-for-all-NI-related/gpm-p/3824398) post in *National Instrument* Linux forum, Installing new ni-daqmx linux driver version 18.1 on Centos 7 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue but mine was due to kernel not letting ni servcies start correctly.

I did:

```
http://ftp.ni.com/support/softlib/visa/NI-VISA
unzip NILinux2023Q3DeviceDrivers.zip
sudo dpkg -i NILinux2023Q3DeviceDrivers/ni-ubuntu2004-drivers-2023Q3.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
reboot
```

When rebooting I got

```
systemd[1]: nipal.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: nipal.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: NI Core Driver Services.
In the session I could see that it was not started correctly
:~$ sudo systemctl status nipal.service
× nipal.service - LSB: NI Core Driver Services
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nipal; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu  UTC; 5min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 966 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nipal start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 6ms
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: NI Core Driver Services...
nipal[977]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nipalk': Operation not permitted
nipal[966]:
nipal[966]: error: nipalk failed to load
nipal[966]: error: Consult the product documentation for support
nipal[966]: error: Or search for solutions on ni.com.
systemd[1]: nipal.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: nipal.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: NI Core Driver Services.
```

From BIOS Enabling the UEFI 3rd party driver load

And disabling the secure boot, solved the issue

```
:~$ sudo systemctl status nipal.service
● nipal.service - LSB: NI Core Driver Services
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/nipal; generated)
     Active: active (running) since Thu  UTC; 21min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 955 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/nipal start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 8876)
     Memory: 3.8M
        CPU: 45ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nipal.service
             ├─1002 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/nipalps /dev/nipalk 
/var/lib/nipal/nipalps.bin
             └─1004 cat /dev/nipalk
systemd[1]: Starting LSB: NI Core Driver Services...
systemd[1]: Started LSB: NI Core Driver Services.
```